# Disallowing branching from a branch in git

Tags: git

In my workflow I almost never want to branch from a branch other than master. A couple of times I have done this by accident when starting a new feature. When I do, it screws up my history when merging.

What's a good way to protect myself from creating a new branch if I am already on a branch? I know about the second parameter to git branch

```
git checkout -b newbranch master
```

but I'm not sure I can retrain myself to always provide it. Ideally I would have this be the default behaviour when I type `git checkout -b newbranch`, or have a warning when I attempt to branch from a branch.

Comment: Branches do not branch from branches. Branches—more properly, branch *names* —identify, or (we say) *point to*, one single commit. I find that the information on the web site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) helps many people get their heads around this particular bit of Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a *bash alias* for `git` that checks for this condition and rewrites your checkout command to follow your convention. In this example below, I preserve a passed in parent branch, but default to `master` when one is not given.

### Bash Alias

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd=$1
opt=$2
branch=$3
parent=$4
if [[ $cmd = "checkout" ]] && [[ $opt = "-b" ]]; then
  if [ -z "$parent" ]; then
    parent="master"
  fi
  /usr/bin/git checkout -b $branch $parent
else
  /usr/bin/git "$@"
fi
```

### Test Command Sequence

```
chmod +x /path/to/git-wrapper.sh
alias git=/path/to/git-wrapper.sh
mkdir test
cd ./test
git init
echo "First line" >readme.md
git add readme.md
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git checkout -b test1
echo "Second line" >> readme.md
git commit -am "Second line"
git checkout -b test2
echo "Third line" >> readme.md
git commit -am "Third line"
git checkout master
git branch -a
git log
git merge test1
git merge test2
```

### Example Output

```
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
[master (root-commit) 11bd292] Initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 readme.md
Switched to a new branch 'test1'
[test1 4ace272] Second line
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Switched to a new branch 'test2'
[test2 54b7fff] Third line
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Switched to branch 'master'
* master
  test1
  test2
Updating 11bd292..4ace272
Fast-forward
 readme.md | 1 +
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
Auto-merging readme.md
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in readme.md
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

A merge failure is our expected result (if the alias were not active, we would have branched from `test1` to `test2` and the merge would have been fast-forwarded. Test it out!

Comment: This looks great, thanks! I will test it out a bit today.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a custom batch/alias that switched to master, maybe pulled master, etc, and then created a new branch.

Another option would be to create branches in your remote repo first. I don't know what solution you're using for your remote repo but this way the process would be more conscious.